# Are very "metagamey" questions allowed?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

So our DM ended on a cliffhanger last time. We just got to see the boss we're gonna fight and got a few very vague clues towards what it was... including the DM throwing over his DM barricade thing resulting in me getting a peak view on the paige of the source book he is using.

Since I'm an extreme munchkin I want to find out what it is and I was about to ask a question on RPG stackexchange, but I wanna make sure that I can.

Other than me having to be really ashamed of doing such a dirty thing, **are there any site rules that prevent me from asking a pure metagaming question?**

Comment: If it's just an [identification question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/68496/8610), that's on topic. You don't have to explain in the question that you're a terrible person. `:-)` (But I don't know if this *is* just an identification question, which is why this isn't an answer.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan thanks, I'll just try asking it. I think I can make it a identification question and not mention how much of a d**k I am ;-)

Comment: You might get downvoted if people don't like the idea of you metagaming, but there's no rule against this sort of question. (And arguably the downvotes would be misplaced.)

Comment: @TuggyNe and others: Why do you answer the question in comments, as opposed to in answers?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**What you're going to use it for doesn't affect whether it's on-topic.**

We're not here to enforce your personal moral code or make sure that you don't use neutral information from the site to do dastardly things to your group.

Keep in mind though that once there is an answer, your question lives forever. If you don't want your GM to ever discover your duplicity, you might want to avoid asking questions in a public forum that's instantly indexed by Google. Even if you don't mention the reasons in the question, consider the possibility of the GM putting 2 and 2 together a week, month, or years later.

If you're OK with the interpersonal risk, it's not really our concern.

Of course, if you asked *this* question on the main site and changed "is it on topic" to "is this a good idea", expect to get a very different answer than this. ;)